# How to handle data binding and dom manipulation for showing/hiding an object in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple overlay directive that is displaying when the user clicks a button.  I'd like to make it such that if the user clicks on the overlay it hides itself.  However, I have a ng-show that is bound a variable on the element of the directive that I use to hide/show the overlay.  The problem is that if I click on the overlay it will hide itself, but I can never re-show the overlay.  Since I'm hiding overlay through a jquery click() handler the bound variable isn't changing to false.  Then when I try to show it again the bound variable isn't changing value, and hence it never shows again.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('overlay', function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="overlay"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function(scope,element,attribs) {
        element.click( function() {
            element.hide();
        });
    }
};
});
```

Here is the usage:

```
<div overlay ng-show="showOverlay">
        <a href="javascript://" class="dialog-close" ng-click="hideHelpOverlay()"><i class="cancel-outline-circle"></i></a>
        <div class="help-video-player">
            <div class="help-video-layer">
                <iframe ng-src="{{getVideoUrl('parent')}}" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="help-overlay">
        <a href="javascript://" ng-click="showHelpOverlay()">?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since showOverlay variable is defined outside the directive this is tricky to manipulate it.

Comment: Why exactly is `showOverlay` tricky to manipulate?

Comment: Notice that showOverlay is defined outside the directive.  So how can the directive automatically handle hiding the overlay when someone clicks on it without knowing how to manipulate showOverlay since it may not be called showOverlay.  What that variable is up to person using the directive.  I don't want to couple overlay to assuming things outside of itself.

Comment: You can pass `showOverlay` to the directive: `overlay="showOverlay"`. It just has to be the same value as for `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formalize zeroflag's suggestion, here's a fiddle with a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/vN8W7/5/

```
<div ng-app='foo' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <div ng-click='showOverlay = true'>Show It</div>
    <div overlay='showOverlay' ng-show='showOverlay'>It's showing!</div>
</div>


var app = angular.module('foo', []).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showOverlay = false;
}).directive('overlay', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            overlay: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-click="overlay = false"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
});
```